# dynamic Scheduler lock with trigger

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I want to make a java scheduler which will run in some particular time interval which will be dynamic(provided from User interface) so I've implemented trigger but how to lock it. I want my scheduler to run only on one instance in multi node environment.

Comment: Hi @nikitajain what library did you implement for trigger? You can use Quartz Scheduler or TaskScheduler of spring.

Comment: I tried it with TaskScheduler but I can't use cron bcoz I want my scheduler to take dynamic values.. let's say if I mentioned 2 in user Interface so it will start running in 
 every 2 seconds. Also my application is deployed on multiple instances but I want to run it on any one of them so how to implement lock. can you share the code if you have.

Comment: @JonathanJohx How can I execute only once a scheduled task inside a cluster using Spring boot when I'm using SchedulerConfigurer because I want dynamic values from UI?

Comment: Can you provide me an example what you try to schedule?